# Devise can't sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

**Hi**

So I'm getting this weird bugs, that after the 2nd user is registered only the last registered user can log in. It say's to everybody else

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

So what can i do?

Comment: What devise version are you using? Do you have two different versions devise gems installed?

Comment: devise (1.1.3, 1.1.2, 1.1.rc1)
devise_oauth2_canvas_facebook (0.0.4)

Comment: So tried specify what gem i'm using in my gem film
gem 'devise', '>= 1.1.3' but no luck..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others getting this problem, i figured it out. in my user.rb i had

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :trackable, :rememberable, :validatable
```

And i found out it was because of :trackable, so now it works.

/ Oluf Nielsen